# ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

```
ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2.
Searched in the following locations:
  -
```

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.2/gradle-3.5.2.pom
  -

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.2/gradle-3.5.2.jar
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.2/gradle-3.5.2.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.2/gradle-3.5.2.jar
    Required by:
        project :
    Open File

```
ext {
    var = '3.5.2'
   var1 = '3.5.2'
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
     repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

we recived this error from my android studio when run my projects
we used online and offline mod but they not worked corectly 
This error has confused me

The following code is related to wrapper

```
ext {
var = '3.5.2'
var1 = '3.5.2'
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

     buildscript {
     repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()

   }
       dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: It's because gradle files have not downloaded compeletly.You should  stay online and sync project.

Comment: Have you add `google()` in your project's level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Add your project level `build.gradle` file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8144311/zahra

I've been online but still  see this error

Comment: yes i have google() in my project

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2637449/md-asaduzzaman

Comment: Do not add this in comment section. Add this gradle file in question by updating it.

Comment: Then check your gradle setting in android studio whether **Offline Work** is enable or not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2637449/md-asaduzzaman

i try in offline mode whit entered path in setting and online mode in both of them i have this error

Comment: once try it Invalidate/caches and restart  and also quit android studio and click on make project and rebuilt project again.

Comment: Show your gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12040838/twisha-kotecha

i try invalidate caches and My problem was not solved

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5049244/arnold-brown

I edited the question code and wrapper is added to my question

Comment: This question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25260172/how-to-check-the-gradle-version-in-android-studio/35847490 solved my issue. You can get latest version from menu **File -> Project Structure...**, and then ensure correct(or latest) **Gradle Plugin version** in `build.gradle` and **Gradle version** inside `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem basically occurs when you are trying to load an old project. The best solution as of my knowledge is to download the links one by one, the project is showing and sync it. Check out the build Gradle files for any outdated dependencies.
Check out if you have

> google()

repo in your project. Make sure you find this line in your dependencies.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
```

Comment: i have this line in my code and when i create a new project  again recived this error

Comment: @Amir You're having the Gradle links so you should download it. Otherwise, you uninstall the Android Studio. Install it again set the correct path variables. If you need any assistance you can search for the same on Youtube. And make sure whenever you are using Android Studio you should be connected to a decent network. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem on Linux (ubuntu)

I tried different ways but the problem still didn't work out.

Finally, I **remove** `/home/(user)/.gradle` directory and restart Android Studio and this error fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps:**

1. Copy paste the below code into `Project` level `build.gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

2. Clean your project from `Build > Clean Project`
3. Rebuild you project from `Build > Rebuild Project`
4. Make Project from `Build > Make Project`
5. Then, `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart`